# Define a color to extract using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image and I need to erase all the green elements.

Right now I'm doing this,

```
hsv = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_green, upper_green = np.array([36, 25, 25]), np.array([70, 255, 255])
mask1 = cv.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
result = cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

cv.imwrite("logo.png", result)
```

The problem is if I do this, I extract all the colors from my image except the green and I want the opposite. I want to keep the original image without green.

For this reason I tried to use two masks, using the green values as limiters. But now I obtain a black image and furthermore I think I'm complicating the method.

```
hsv = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_green, upper_green = np.array([36, 25, 25]), np.array([70, 255, 255])
mask1 = cv.inRange(hsv, np.array([0, 25, 25]), lower_green)
mask2 = cv.inRange(hsv, upper_green, np.array([179, 25, 25]))
mask = cv.bitwise_or(mask1, mask2)
result = cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask2)

cv.imwrite("logo.png", result)
```

I'm doing correctly? How can I do this? I always find explanations about how to find the color to eliminate the rest, but not my goal.

Thank you!

Comment: please illustrate your issue with pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to invert your mask.

```
result = cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=~mask)
```

Note the `~`, that inverts the mask.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand well but if you want to work with green channel why did you convert image to HSV?
in RGB; extract channels, remove green channel (or range) and merge channels again.